# (newbie) Get data from array of objects using ng-repeat and for loop

Tags: angularjs

I have to access some objects inside an array:

```
.success(function(data) { 
    $scope.activities = data.result[0].attributes 
});
```

And I can access this particular index, as expected, inside my view with

```
<div ng-repeat="x in activities">
    <p>{{x.name}}: {{x.value}}</p>
</div>
```

Now obviously, this only returns the first object in the array, at index 0. (Right?). So I figure I have to somehow loop the function..

```
.success(function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
        $scope.activities = data.result[i].attributes;
    }
});
```

As far as I can tell, the actual for loop is working.. but I need help in the next step exposing this to my view.

Here is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZukY3Oq8vYvghfCruHx?p=preview

(although the data is not available, I have added what the response looks like in the comments)

Comment: Could you do a plunker?

Comment: my data structure looks like this: 
{  
   "requestId":"14213#155c8de2578",
   "result":[  
      {  
         "id":75843491,
         "leadId":5334578,
         "activityDate":"2016-07-06T06:45:11Z",
         "activityTypeId":46,
         "primaryAttributeValue":"Web",
         "attributes":[  ]
      },
      {  },
      {  }

(sorry, that's messy.. I'll put that in a plunker)

Comment: You should know that the `success` and `error` methods are deprecated and you should don't use them. You must use **`THEN`**.. it's just a tip (it still works).

Comment: Here it is formatted nicer in a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZukY3Oq8vYvghfCruHx?p=info

Comment: I don't think it's that. 

In my HTML I have the setter nested higher up, and all subsequently nested controllers are using the 'getter'.

Comment: well, here it works fine. You can see the errors in `Chrome Dev Tools` without the blank array in module.

Comment: It currently "works" in the sense that I can either access the first object data.result[0] or the last object data.result[i]. Does that make sense?

Comment: I said that way you're doing you can't even acessing your controller, here we go to the **SECOND** problem.

Comment: I think we're getting caught up on something not really relevant. I'll update my plunker to include all my code. Give me a second to remove any private info.

Comment: I've updated the plunker. as you can see it's compiling OK.

Comment: It's the same as before: https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZukY3Oq8vYvghfCruHx?p=info

Comment: VM443 angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to help me, but that's clearly because the .js files listed in the index were unsuccessful in the get. I'd rather just assume that it's compiling OK on my machine (it is), and try and address the initial question of how to access my binding.

Comment: @Nicho You want to loop over all the elements of `data.result` right?

Comment: @Chinni yes exactly. if I do something like: 'var response = data.result[i].attributes; $scope.activities = responses; console.log(response);' I can see that my console is is getting all my my elements.. but I can't work out how to make my {{activities}} binding display this.. it seems like my {{activities}} is ending up as the final object in my array.

Comment: @Nicho It is getting updated to the last element of the array because of the for loop. You are overwriting your `scope` variable `activities` in each iteration. So the last value it gets overwritten to will be the last element of the `results` array. Instead of iterating in the controller, you can use two `ng-repeat` clauses. Please check my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per my understanding of your issue, you can solve it by using two `ng-repeat` clauses.

Your controller code,

```
.success(function(data) { 
    $scope.ativitiesArray = data.result; 
});
```

Your html code,

```
<div ng-repeat="activities in activitiesArray track by $index">
    <div ng-repeat="x in activities.attributes track by $index">
        <p>{{x.name}}: {{x.value}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've added `track by $index` phrase to `ng-repeat` as it will increase performance. Also, as per suggestions in the comments, please avoid using `.success()`. It is recommended to use `.then()`.

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this.. it seems like it should work.. `<div ng-repeat="x in activitiesArray">{{x.attributes}} /* -> getting there.. I get this: [{"name": "myName","value":"myValue"}{"name":"anotherName","value":"anotherValue"}][{"name": "myName","value":"myValue"}{"name":"anotherName","value":"anotherValue"}]*/ `

but I can't seem to figure out why my next nested `<div ng-repeat="x in attributes">{{name}} {{value}}` isn't working

Comment: @Nicho Please check my updated code. I've forgot to add `.attributes` in the `ng-repeat`. Hope you got the logic.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. It's all coming together now!.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the `JSON` data you pasted in [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZukY3Oq8vYvghfCruHx?p=preview) is invalid, I don't know what `attributes` means, if it's just an *object* or it's an *array* of objects, anyway I made it as a single object.

**EDIT**

Since now I know `attributes` is an **Array** of *objects*, you can achieve what you want using [special repeats](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points).

Here's a snippet working:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.getLeadActivities = function() {
        var url = 'xxxxxxxx.mktorest.com';
        var endpoint = '/rest/v1/activities.json';
        var activityTypeIds = '46';
        var access_token = $scope.access_token;
        var leadIds = $scope.leadId;
        var nextPageToken = $scope.pagingToken;
       
        // This is your data from API
        var data = {  
           "requestId":"14213#155c8de2578",
           "success":true,
           "nextPageToken":"EOXAPD2V5UOJ5B3S5GGP7NUCX6UI6BFXCWHPJXF245PN2QTGMF3Q====",
           "moreResult":false,
           "result":[  
              {  
                 "id":75843491,
                 "leadId":5334578,
                 "activityDate":"2016-07-06T06:45:11Z",
                 "activityTypeId":46,
                 "primaryAttributeValue":"Web",
                 "attributes":[  
                    {  
                       "name":"myDataName",
                       "value":"myDataValue"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {  
                 "id":75843491,
                 "leadId":5334578,
                 "activityDate":"2016-07-06T06:45:11Z",
                 "activityTypeId":46,
                 "primaryAttributeValue":"Web",
                 "attributes":[  
                    {  
                       "name":"myDataName2",
                       "value":"myDataValue2"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {  
                 "id":75843491,
                 "leadId":5334578,
                 "activityDate":"2016-07-06T06:45:11Z",
                 "activityTypeId":46,
                 "primaryAttributeValue":"Web",
                 "attributes":[  
                    {  
                       "name":"myDataName3",
                       "value":"myDataValue3"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        };

        // You'll put it inside the THEN method of your $http.get
        $scope.activities = data.result;
      }
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="getLeadActivities()">Get Lead Activities</button>
  <div ng-repeat-start="activity in activities"></div>
  <ul ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="attr in activity.attributes">
    <li ng-bind="attr.name + ': ' + attr.value"></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My attributes is an array of objects. But that said, I'm not sure why I can't get your example to work. I'm not getting an errors.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - that worked. So it seems it's all about nesting the ng-repeat? I'll do some research on ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. Thanks again for your help.